# How do I add data to a table cell using AJAX, MySQL and PHP under the following circumstances:

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, href

In a html table with two columns, the first column is populated from php and mysql. I need to make the first column values links that when clicked make an AJAX call to populate the adjacent cell with values obtained from MySQL. I have been able to get the first column values using the following:

```
<html>

<?php 
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_name = "db";        
$db_user = "user";
$db_word = "password";


$connect=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_word, $db_name);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT people FROM users");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>People</th>
<th>Ages</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['people'] . "</a></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connect);
?>

</html>
```

I need to make the first column value a link that retrieves an age value from MySQL when clicked using AJAX. Any suggestions examples?

Comment: Change your SQL statement to grab a unique id along with the 'People' column.  Add that unique id as an attribute to your html table rows.  Then set up a jQuery listener to listen for clicks on <td>s, grab the unique id, and send that id to a PHP backend to query your database for the ages.

Answer (score 0):

Change your initial SQL query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT people, SOME_UNIQUE_ID FROM users");
```

...

Add the unique id to your html table rows:

```
echo "<td id = '". $row['SOME_UNIQUE_ID'] . "'>" . $row['people'] . "</td>";
```

...

Add a jQuery listener:

```
 <script>

    $('body').on('click', 'td', function() {
     var myID = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax(
       data: myID 
       foo: write your own ajax,
       bar:....
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: The reason this does not solve the problem is because the second column is a sum of ages people with that name, not a direct relationship to the particular person. Such as this: SELECT people, SUM(ages) FROM users WHERE people ='jon', with 'jon' being the link. So clicking on that link would have put the data from that sql statement into the adjacent cell. Sorry for not being clear enough. Thanks for the start though.

Comment: Edit your question, then. Seriously, how do you expect anyone to help you when you don't include the actual problem in your question?  Do you have a SQL question or an AJAX question?

Comment: Again sorry, if it was not clear enough. If you have better way to frame the question I would welcome the help. I'm a total newb, I could not find any documentation on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it is an AJAX question ultimately. First I need to make the first column a properly formatted link that calls an AJAX script that gets the data from MySql and puts in just that adjacent cell, not the entire second column.